# Inserting New Record to The Database Overwrites Existing Record C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have designed a student survey to evaluate instructors. The survey consist of 20 questions. what I want to do have each student to login and record their answer to a database. I was able to design the whole thing however, every time I take a survey the New Record Overwrites Existing Record.I would like to be able for all answers to be saved in one row for each student.

I'm really under time pressure and any help on this will be greatly appreciate it.

**Here is the code on the Q1 page**

```
if (Session["USER_ID"] != null )
              {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Survey (Q1,Q1_Comments) values (@Q1,@Q1_Comments)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1", radListQ1.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1_Comments", txtQ1Comments.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Q2.aspx");
        }
```

**and here is the code in Q2 question**

```
Protected void btnQ2Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["USER_ID"] != null)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Survey SET Q2 = @Q2, Q2_Comments = @Q2_Comments ", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q2", radListQ2.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q2_Comments", txtQ2Comments.Text);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Response.Redirect("Q3.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Please help, I'm suspecting the insert/Update statement is what causing that.

I aslo, would like to mention that each question is in a separate page and that is why I'm inserting the update.

**Edit**

Currently, My DB Structure is like this

**Survey Table**
Survey_ID (PK)
Username (Fk)
Student_ID (fK)
Course_ID (FK)
Q1
Q1_Comments
Q2
Q2_Comments
Q3
Q3_Comments
Q4
Q4_Comments
...... to Q20

**Student Table**
Student_ID (PK)
Last_Name
First_Name
Username
Password

**Course_student Table**
Student_ID (PK)
Course_ID (PK)
Instructor_ID (PK)
Survey_ID (PK)

**Course Table**
Course_ID
Class_Title
Instructor_Last
Instructor_First
Term
Section_ID
Course_Number

**Instructor Table**
Instructor_ID (PK)
Last_Name
First_Name
Username
Password

**Login Page code**

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select s.Student_ID, c.Course_ID,s.First_Name, s.Last_Name, c.Class_Title, c.Course_ID, c.Instructor_Last, c.Instructor_First, c.Term, c.Section_ID, c.Course_Number,e.Instructor_ID from Student S Join Course_Student e ON (s.Student_ID = e.Student_ID) Join Course c ON(c.Course_ID = e.Course_ID) where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserTable where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["USER_ID"] = dt;
            Response.Redirect("Successful_Login.aspx");
        }
```

**Successful_Login.aspx**

```
public partial class Successful_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["USER_ID"];
        lblName.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();//your cloumn name;

        DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)Session["USER_ID"];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Remove("USER_ID");
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session["USER_ID"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Loggedout.aspx");
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string instructorName = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text + ", " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        string courseSession= GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text + "-" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        string term = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;
        string studentID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text;
        string CourseID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text;

        Session["USER_ID1"] = instructorName;
        Session["USER_ID2"] = courseSession;
        Session["USER_ID3"] = term;
        Session["USER_ID4"] = studentID;
        Session["USER_ID5"] = CourseID;



        Response.Redirect("Q1.aspx");
    }
```

**Q1 Page**

```
if (Session["USER_ID"] != null )
          {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Survey (Q1,Q1_Comments) values (@Q1,@Q1_Comments)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1", radListQ1.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1_Comments", txtQ1Comments.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Q2.aspx");
    }
```

**Q2 Page**

```
if (Session["USER_ID"] != null )
          {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Survey (Q1,Q1_Comments) values (@Q1,@Q1_Comments)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1", radListQ1.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q1_Comments", txtQ1Comments.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Q2.aspx");
    }
```

Can you please show me how to write correctly using my variable names.

Comment: What does the schema for the surveys look like? What other fields does your survey table have?

Comment: You have no Where statement in the Q2. So It doesn't know which record you want to update. And if you want it in a different row, you need insert

Comment: How would you write the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

While it may not directly answer your question it may lead you to better organise your DB, in my eyes you will need to change your DB Design to accomodate multiple users and multiple questions with respective answers so your tables should look something like this

```
Table Users
-----------
UserId (PK)
FirstName
LastName
...

Table Questions
---------------
QuestionId (PK)
QuestionText
...

Table Answers
-------------
AnswerId (PK, Autonumber)
UserId      - Unique constraint
QuestionId  - Unique constraint
Answer
...
```

with such structure you will be able to do something like this then :

```
if (Session["USER_ID"] != null )
              {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Answers (UserId, QuestionId, Answer) values (@p1, @p2, @p3)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Session["USER_ID"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", radListQ1.SelectedValue); //reference question_id field here
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p3", txtQ1Comments.Text); // reference answer field here

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Survey.aspx?Q=" + NextQuestionId);
        }
```